# Programmatically draw a bitmap to a WPF Canvas?

Tags: wpf

How can I programmatically draw a bitmap to a WPF Canvas?  (or should I do something else entirely?)   I will have about 40 moving images.

Comment: Could you add more detail. You do not seem to be getting the answer you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to dynamically create and modify bitmaps, then use a [WritableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx). You can place these on a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar, but I wanted some logic on each image(object) so I created a UserControl with an image and just add the UserControl to the canvas.